# Need help solving this differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours now and haven't been able to make progress. The original problem is below with my work and progress beneath it.

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y(x^3-y^3)}{x(2y^3-x^3)}$$

First:
Let $y=ux$  then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}x + u$

substituting in and simplifying I am able to separate the variables:
$$-\frac{2u^3-1}{u^4+u} du= \frac{1}{x} dx$$
After this i can't find a way to integrate the left side. is there an easier way, or maybe another substitution that i could have used?

Comment: This can be integrated with partial sums.  $u^4+u$ factors as $u(u+1)(u^2-u+1)$

Comment: @user2056637: Did the answers resolve your problem? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the help everyone. I forgot to add a 2 in the numerator 2x^3... in the original post. But have been able to work through the integration.

Answer (score 1):

You were doing fine, but somehow something went South in the simplification.

We have:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{y}{x} \dfrac{x^3-y^3}{2y^3-x^3}$$

We make the substitution:

$$y = vx \rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx} = v + xv'$$

When we substitute, we get:

$$ xv' = -\dfrac{v^4}{2v^3 - 1} $$

This separates into:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{2v^3-1}{v^4}~dv = -\int \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

Comment: Needs a TU, too! +1

Answer (score 0):

I believe you lost the $+u$ term from $dy/dx=(du/dx)x+u$. If you do the algebra right, I believe you end up with a much easier integral. I get$$\frac{dx}x=\frac{1-2u^3}{u^4}du$$but don't take my word for it, I make lots of mistakes.

**P.S.** I guess I got it right this time, because I see Amzoti came up with the same answer!